# Почему глагол "управлять" непереходный?

Tags: глаголы, винительный-падеж, творительный-падеж

Ведь, действие переходит к объекту. И вопрос "управлять что?" вроде звучит нормально.

Например: "Я управляю машину рулем и педалями." – Что управляю? Машину. Чем управляю? Рулем и педалями.

Все вроде сходится, но нет. Правильно будет: "Я управляю машиной рулем и педалями."

Это просто традиция такая, или у меня какое-то понимание не хватает?

Comment: Mostly this verb is intransitive, but it is listed as transitive above because it has passive participles. **The object is in the instrumental case**: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ваши рассуждения не лишены смысла. По-видимому, в 18-м веке оба варианта были допустимы.

Винительный:

- Московскую **губернию управлять** и доносить Сенату Василью Ершову.
  [Петр I. Указ об учреждении Правительствующего Сената и о персональном его составе (1711)](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?docid=bWFpbi9zb3VyY2UvcHJlMTk1MC94dmlpaS9kb2tfcGV0cl9pL3VrYXpfNi54bWw%3D&dpp=100&expand=full&expdiap=11%3A17&lang=ru&level1=0&lex1=%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C&mode=main&nodia=1&parent1=0&seed=13492&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=semx&sid=14&sort=i_grtagging&spd=5&text=lexgramm)

Творительный:

- А **артиллериею управлял** генерал-порутчик от артиллерии Брюс.
  [«Обстоятельная реляция» о Полтавской битве (1709)](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?docid=bWFpbi9zb3VyY2UvcHJlMTk1MC94dmlpaS9yZWxhdGlvL2RvY18wMS54bWw%3D&dpp=100&expand=full&expdiap=11%3A17&lang=ru&level1=0&lex1=%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C&mode=main&nodia=1&parent1=0&seed=13492&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=semx&sid=14&sort=i_grtagging&spd=5&text=lexgramm)

Причём один и тот же автор может использовать разные варианты в одном и том же тексте:

- в сем Городе быть Генералу Полицейместеру, которому даны за Его Величества собственною рукою пункты, как ему свое врученное **дело управлять**
  [А. И. Богданов. Описание Санктпетербурга (1751)](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?docid=bWFpbi9zb3VyY2UvcHJlMTk1MC94dmlpaS9ib2dkYW5vdl9haS9ib2dkXzAxLnhtbA%3D%3D&dpp=100&expand=full&expdiap=3570%3A3576&lang=ru&level1=0&lex1=%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C&mode=main&nodia=1&parent1=0&seed=13492&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=semx&sid=3573&sort=i_grtagging&spd=5&text=lexgramm)
- Регламент Адмиралтейской, во управление той Коллегии, которая **Адмиралтейством управляет**
  [А. И. Богданов. Описание Санктпетербурга (1751)](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?docid=bWFpbi9zb3VyY2UvcHJlMTk1MC94dmlpaS9ib2dkYW5vdl9haS9ib2dkXzAxLnhtbA%3D%3D&dpp=100&expand=full&expdiap=3818%3A3824&lang=ru&level1=0&lex1=%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C&mode=main&nodia=1&parent1=0&seed=13492&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=semx&sid=3821&sort=i_grtagging&spd=5&text=lexgramm)

И даже в одной фразе (хотя я думаю, это всё же ошибка):

- если правило справедливости. и несправедливости, долженствующее **управлять** равно **действия** невежи, как **и учением** просвещенного человека, не будет для судий простой вопрос о учиненном поступке, то состояние гражданина странным приключениям будет подвержено.
  [Екатерина II. Наказ Комиссии о составлении проекта нового Уложения (1767)](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?docid=bWFpbi9zb3VyY2UvcHJlMTk1MC94dmlpaS9la2F0ZXJpbmFfaWkvbmFrYXoxODY3LnhtbA%3D%3D&dpp=100&expand=full&expdiap=410%3A416&lang=ru&level1=0&lex1=%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C&mode=main&nodia=1&parent1=0&seed=13492&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=semx&sid=413&sort=i_grtagging&spd=5&text=lexgramm)

Но уже к концу 18-го века такое употребление устаревает. Последнее такое употребление, которое я смог найти в корпусе - несколько фрагментов из книги «Историческое описаніе россійской коммерціи» М. Д. Чулкова, 1786г.

Answer (score 6):

The verb *управлять* is oblique transitive (*косвенно-переходный*).

That means that it can take a direct object, but the object is put in a case other than the accusative.

The direct object of this verb should be in the instrumental. That's how the verb works.

If you look at Russian cases (as well as cases in any other inflected language, for that matter), you'll see that while most of them do have a prevailing usage pattern (the accusative is *mainly* for objects, the dative is *mainly* for the recipients of an action etc.), this usage pattern is more like a general guideline rather than a strict rule.

In Latin, the dative can be used as *dativus finalis, dativus ethicus, dativus auctoris* and in all other kinds of roles which don't have anything to do with being on the business end of some action, despite the fact that it looks like this from the point of view of formal syntactic analysis. This is something you have to learn outright when you study Latin.

It's the same way in Russian; Russian verbs accept their arguments in a certain case and maybe with a certain preposition, which sometimes doesn't make sense.

When I was a kid, I was baffled when I first learned the expression *ревновать кого-то (А) к кому-то (Б)* ("to be jealous of someone (A) because of someone else (B)"). It didn't make sense to me right away. But as any other speaker, I learned how to use it and now it just sounds natural to me (unless I go over it again and again in my head until it doesn't).

Over time, verbs can change the way they govern their arguments. It used to be *следовать кому-то*, "to follow someone", and these days it's *следовать за кем-то*. It used to be *скучать по ком-то* "miss someone", in the prepositional, but now it's falling out of use in favor of *скучать по кому-то*, in the dative. In various Russian dialects, it's even *скучать за кем-то*. The latter is non-standard usage, but it's worthy enough of mention in almost every other style guide out there.

This exact thing happened with the verb *управлять*. It did use to govern a direct object in the accusative:

> - И послаша о том бити челом ко благочестивому царю и государю нашему, чтоб государь их пожаловал: дал имъ в Казань своих бояр и правителей, кому их здержати и управляти.
> - Бывшу собору на Москвѣ и избраша Коломенского епископа Геронтиа, яко достоина суща управляти богомъ поручное ему стадо.
> - И аще така будеши вся своя дела управляти, то всяк тебя будет блажити и добрым человеком будеши слыти.

but then it switched the pattern and now it governs the instrumental.

The role the cases play in a sentence is not defined by a strict rule, although they do tend to follow patterns. When you learn a new verb, you also have to learn how it governs its arguments. Most of the time, it's intuitive, but sometimes it isn't.

Comment: Very interesting. Do you know any other oblique-transitive verbs?

Comment: To answer my own question, here are some other oblique-transitive verbs, along with participles: достигать, достичь, достигнуть (чего?) - достигаемый, достигнутый, избега́ть (чего?) - избегаемый, польстить (кому?) - польщённый, руководить (кем?) - руководимый, предводительствовать (кем?) - предводительствуемый, отомстить (кому?) - отомщённый.

Comment: @SergeySlepov You may want to take a look at [rusgram.ru/Переходность](http://rusgram.ru/Переходность). It offers in-depth analysis of all kinds of verb-object relations found in the Russian corpus.

Comment: "When I was a kid, I was baffled when I first learned the expression ревновать кого-то (А) к кому-то (Б)" - me to! I still think this expression is weird.

Comment: @il--ya compare with соревноваться с кем-то- to compete with someone. That's same root (and curiously matches latin *rivinus* - competitor, English *rival* maybe related) but verb is reflexive version of ревновать.

Answer (score 5):

> Почему глагол "управлять" непереходный?

С точки зрения формальной классификации глаголов -- потому что он не требует дополнения в винительном падеже без предлога. А вот почему он требует дополнения не в винительном падеже, а в творительном -- это уже непростой вопрос...

Во-первых, глагол "управлять" не один такой. Есть целый ряд глаголов, объединённых общим смыслом **владения и распоряжения**, которые требуют дополнения именно в творительном падеже:

- "располагать временем"
- "обладать свойством"
- "владеть домом"
- "командовать отрядом"
- "распоряжаться имуществом"
- "заведовать кафедрой"
- "дирижировать оркестром"
- "править миром"
- "руководить отделом"
- "рулить лодкой" и т.п.

Глагол "управлять" прекрасно вписывается в этот ряд, поэтому словосочетание "управлять чем?" нам кажется совершенно естественным, а сочетание "управлять что?" наоборот, представляется ломаным. Особенно плохо (на мой слух) оно звучит, когда в качестве объекта выступает что-то нематериальное: "*управлять страну", "*управлять эмоции", "*управлять судьбу".

Но с другой стороны есть глаголы со сходным смыслом управления, принимающие обычные прямые дополнения: "вести машину", "контролировать процесс", "направлять последователей". Так что приведённое в предыдущем абзаце наблюдение нельзя считать непреложным правилом или строгим объяснением. Скорее, иллюстрацией.

Comment: Ну, располагать, обладать, распоряжатся и заведовать, это очевидно непереходные глаголы. И вопрос "чем?" к ним звучит нормально. Только мне неясно почему рядом с ними находятся и глаголы у которых есть очевидное воздействие на объект действия? То есть по определению "переходные". И почему например "контролировать" (по сути синоним) не вписывается в этот ряд?

Comment: @johnfound, наверно это уже вопрос личного образа мыслей. "Располагать" и "обладать" означают, что я владею вещью, а значит я могу оказать на ней влияние. "Распоряжаться" и "заведовать" означают как раз прямое управляющее воздействие. И всем этим глаголам по смыслу обязательно нужен пациенс. В моём понимании разница между "могу воздействовать" и "воздействую" не столь сильна, чтобы запретить им относиться к одному ряду. Ну, на определённом уровне абстракции...

Comment: @johnfound А у глагола "контролировать" основной смысл - "проверять", для которого привычной формой объекта является винительный падеж. Возвращаясь к исходному вопросу, тут не всё однозначно. Я не в состоянии объяснить почему эти глаголы требуют именно такие падежи. Я могу только показать определённые закономерности и заверить вас, что творительный падеж у глагола "управлять" не вызывает удивления.